# Need to pass checkbox value along with textbox values (php)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am using a contact form with ajax/php/jquery.

i have added checkboxes to the form. name of checkboxes is called 'selection [ ]'

i am having a hard time getting the value of the checkboxes to output to email text.

when i do by using a .implode statement, it loops through the foreach statement and outputs the checked box value 5 times.

I am trying to work ona website for a friend, i am not a php expert and i am merely a beginner.

pls help.

below is the code:

```
$from = 'Sales@ipsnypro.com';
$sendTo = 'dave.torres@aecom.com';
$subject = 'New message from IPSNYPRO.com';
$fields = array('name' => 'First Name:', 'surname' => 'Last Name:', 'phone'      => 'Phone:', 'email' => 'Email:', 'message' => 'Message:', 'selection' => 'I am interested in:'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Contact form has been successfully submitted. Thank you, We will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


try
{
$emailText = "You have new message from www.IPSNYPRO.com\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

   if (isset($fields[$key])) {
     $emailText .= "$fields[$key] $value\n";

   }
}

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));  

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: also, since adding 'selection => ' i am interested in:' to the $fields = array statement, i am not getting in the email body "i am interested in: array

Answer (score 0):

It's probably important to note that a [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) is not normally sent in the HTTP request by the browser, unless it has been checked.

> - **checked**
>
>   - When the value of the type attribute is checkbox, the presence of this Boolean attribute indicates that the control is selected by default; otherwise it is ignored.
>
> [From the documentatoin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

As such, it's more sane to explicitly check for the values that you expect from the form, rather than blindly assume the client will *always* send you all of the values (*or only those values*) which you expect.

I'm assuming your `$fields` array contains the names of the expected `input` fields on your form. So, assuming that is true, we can safely do this instead of your `foreach` loop.

```
/* This will initialize the array with all keys in $fields with their default values
   if they aren't already in $_POST, making sure you always get what you expect */
$data = array_intersect_key($_POST, $fields) + $fields;

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($key) . " = " . htmlspecialchars($value) . "<br>\n";
}
```

### N.B

You should be using `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` to properly escape input values supplied by the client, since they cannot be trusted as safe in HTML context here.